# python not writing when a space in text

Tags: python

I have working code which writes 'hi' in text file if 'Welcome' is present in the next line.

But, if the next line begins with whitespace before word 'Welcome' then it doesnot displays 'hi'

Code:

```
with open('afile.txt', 'r+') as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    index = 0
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith("Welcome"):
            a.insert(index, "hi")
            break
        index += 1
    # Go to start of file and clear it
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    # Write each line back
    for line in a:  
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

#### Input: afile.txt

```
   Welcome here
Good place
```

#### Expected output:

```
hi
   Welcome here     
Good place
```

I need to preserve my indendation also. How can I do that?

Comment: you are asking about why it doesn't output `hi` when the line starts with `Wel come` instead of `welcome`?

Comment: This is becaause you are using item.startswith("Welcome")
When "Welcome" contains a space, it's actually "Wel come", and thus startswith returns False.
What would your expected output be if Welcome contained a space ?

Comment: i meant the space from indentation

Comment: But where are you inserting this tab/space before 'Welcome' ?

Comment: use `enumerate` if you want to index elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently checking for `Welcome` directly. Instead, strip your line of whitespaces, and use the following condition instead

```
if item.strip().startswith("Welcome"):
```

**EDIT**

I see you've done `rstrip` earlier in `a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]`. Do a `lstrip` instead to remove whitespaces from the left. However, if you do this, your indentation will not be preserved.

Comment: can i preserve my indentation after writing hi?

Comment: @Chaeltrims For that, you will have to go with my initial answer to use `if item.strip().startswith("Welcome"):`, the edited part of my answer won't preserve indentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the line :

`a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]`

replace `rstip` with `strip` and you are good to go ...